# Css scale width of div to width of absolute positioned sibling

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to create a custom dropdown

[image]

We have a description: `Choose a value:` and then the actual dropdown with selected value `x`. `a`, `b`, `c`, `long-value` etc. are the rows available in the dropdown. The rows of the dropdown are absolute positioned.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="description" style="">Choose a value: </div>
    <div class="custom-select">
      <div class="selected">x</div>
      <div class="options">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>long-value</div>
        <div>e</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.description {
}

.custom-select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.selected {
}

.options {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I'm a little bit stuck, how can I scale the width of my `.selected` to be equal to the width of my `.options` here? And how do I place `long-value` on one line? I.e. it shouldn't be wrapped.

https://jsfiddle.net/nwnso1ct/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex and direction column and you won't need absolute position:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="">Choose a value: </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;position: relative;display: flex;flex-direction:column;">
      <div>x</div>
      <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>long-value</div>
        <div>e</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As you're expecting to show a *selected* value then allow to select others from a list, styling an actual **select** element might be a better approach